# swap numbers in javascript using array destruction

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructor

```
let a=5
let b=10

//a,b=b,a
[a,b]=[b,a];
console.log(a,b);
```

**[a,b]=[b,a];
^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'b' before initialization
at Object. (C:\javascript\Telusko\swap.js:5:4)
**

i dont why iam getting this error, can anyone help me.

Comment: Your code is being interpreted as `let b=10[a,b]...` because you didn't set a `;`.

Comment: @deceze It worked, but semicolon is not mandatory right? Why it happened

Comment: Read the duplicate linked above.